# downloading file windows mobile 6.x

Tags: c#, download, windows-mobile-6

Hmm i tried to downlaod data from myurl/test.txt i find how to do that but codes below:

```
String forecastAdress = "myurl/test.txt";

            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(forecastAdress);
            //httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

            System.IO.Stream dataStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);

            String forecastData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            listBox1.Text = forecastData;

            textBox1.Text = forecastData;
            streamReader.Close();
            httpResponse.Close();
```

but it occures error in

```
 System.IO.Stream dataStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

> Could not establish connection to network.

I'm wondering it is connection fail or something is wrong i code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the device doesn't have a connection to that particular host, or it doesn't have any connectivity at all.

I'm assuming that "myurl/test" is something you changed and isn't what you're actually passing to the device, because that's not a valid URL unless you've got custom DNS going on that makes it resolve.

Comment: no ti looks somehow like this http://myserver/odbierajka/wiadomosc.txt device got some connection becouse i can brows sites

Comment: OK, but can you actually view the text file from Internet explorer on the device?

Comment: when i tried connection was lost, and i cant brow any other sites either

Comment: Id like to ask another question after downloading data and parse it int xml file how to bind it in textboxlist?